# IF Unique ID of Android device changed What is the unchanged

Tags: android, fixed, uniqueidentifier

If **Unique ID in Android** device can be modified on **rooted device** or by **Factory reset**
Is there something on the android devices that **could not be altered or changed** and at the same time it **must be unique** ?

Comment: Perhaps look into https://github.com/vieux/OpenUDID

Comment: Can you refer to the **discussed-to-death** Duplicate Post please